# Html textarea changing the value of a encoded javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, cryptojs

I'm working on this [Encryption Cipher](http://toastext.com/cipher.html) using [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/wikis/QuickStartGuide_v3beta.wiki) for people who want to encrypt their messages. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem decrypting any messages that is encrypted using "NoPadding" padding. After hours and hours of testing the program for bugs, I finally found out what the problem was. I turns out that, when I append the encrypted javascript string into the HTML textarea, it changed the value of the string. Therefore, when I tried to decrypt the value from the textarea, it didn't work.

```
    <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
    <button onclick="encrypting_without_textarea()">encrypting without textarea</button>
    <button onclick="encrypting_with_textarea()">encrypting with textarea</button>
```

HTML

```
    function encrypting_without_textarea(){
        var textarea_element = document.getElementById("textarea");

        var encryptionKey = "fkjasdlfkdsanfknlasknflsjkanflnasjkfnjknskjnfnlsnf";
        var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encryptionKey);
        var value = "Multi-stability is the tendency of ambiguous perceptual experiences to move unstably back and forth between alternative interpretations. Some objects can be perceived in more than one way. An example from below in the section of figure/ground.";
        var paddingObject = CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding;
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {mode:CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding:paddingObject});

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {mode:CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding:paddingObject});
        var msg = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        alert(msg); 
    }
```

The one above is decrypted straight from the encrypted message and it works, and the one below is decrypted with the value from from the textarea but it returns an error.

```
             function encrypting_with_textarea(){
                var textarea_element = document.getElementById("textarea");

                var encryptionKey = "fkjasdlfkdsanfknlasknflsjkanflnasjkfnjknskjnfnlsnf";
                var key  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encryptionKey);
                var value = "Multi-stability is the tendency of ambiguous perceptual experiences to move unstably back and forth between alternative interpretations. Some objects can be perceived in more than one way. An example from below in the section of figure/ground.";
                var paddingObject = CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding;
                var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {mode:CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding:paddingObject});
                textarea_element.value = encrypted;

                var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textarea_element.value, key, {mode:CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding:paddingObject});
                var msg = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                alert(msg); 
                //Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
            }
```

Here is the plnkr [link](http://plnkr.co/1Hu6F19yFq3LxPBNDOrN). I understand that the value append to the textarea has change, but how? And, how do I change/encode the string so that the code can be display in the textarea and copy so that the message can be paste/decode with out it being corrupted. I'm open to any solutions, simpler the better?

Comment: Is the webpage encoding declared as utf-8?

Comment: Yes. I added <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> at the top.

Comment: Does `key` become part of result? What is expected result of `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encryptionKey)` where `encryptionKey` is a string?

Comment: No, not for the test page. And yes the key is store as a string for you convenience.

Comment: Have not tried `CryptoJS`. Which parameters do `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify` and expect, respectively; string, object or either, and what are return values of the calls? Is "Salted__" expected at beginning of `.value` of `textarea` element?

Comment: Here CryptoJS(https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/wikis/QuickStartGuide_v3beta.wiki), it explains the process and outputs. The  "Salted__" isn't a salt, its a authentication hash for decoding. I'm planning to add random iv in the future as a salt the encrypted message, but I need this part to work first.

Comment: @Danny Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co of linked test page?

Comment: Here is the plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/1Hu6F19yFq3LxPBNDOrN

Comment: `ecrypted` is an object, not a string.

Comment: Thanks! In other word I have to store it as a file? is there a way to append the data to the text area uncorrupted?

Comment: Yes. Was able to set `.value` of `textarea` to `encrypted.ciphertext.toString();` then use `var msg = decrypted.toString();`, though not certain if that is the result that you are expecting http://plnkr.co/edit/SWab9uZrlygjLPJudC9u?p=preview. Have not yet tried other methods of the object, or other means to format string to original input.

Comment: I'm just going to have to re-write the entire decryption system around it being an object or find a way to make it into a string. Thanks, and have a happy new year.